# I Can't Change my div Sizes When Using oriantation

Tags: resize, autoresize

High all.
I have a site that works ok on MOST devices.
However, I'm having a problem with resizing when the screen is for an iPhone 13 mini.
I have the screen size set at 650X1315.
All is fine until the phone is in horizontal. At this point my css fails to do anything.

I have:
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) and (orientation:landscape)

I've tried changing lots of properties, but neither the div form will increase to contain the textarea, or will the textarea reduce to stay within the form div.

I've tried MANY css rules but nothing works for me in

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) and (orientation:landscape)

Everything else works with width fit-content

Can anyone suggest anything please?

I've included an image to show this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add `text-area: max-width:80%`

also try to use other simulation's tools for iPhone
may it has bug

Comment: I did indeed Mohamed, thanks.